# C# WebApi Azure Application Logging not working

Tags: c#, azure, logging, asp.net-web-api

I'm using a c# webapi hosted on Azure and I'm using the System.Diagnostics.Trace to perform some logging. On the app configuration I've activated the application logging
[image]
and on the code I user `Trace.TraceInformation("Something to inform")`

but the .csv is not generated on the Azure Blob Storage. The only thing that appears is when I make the deployment
[image]

I have this type of system working successfully on other apps but I can't understand why it won't work on this

when running on localhost, the *Traces* appear on the output window