# Azure Functions Application logs aren't collected on blob container

Tags: azure, azure-webjobssdk, azure-web-app-service, azure-functions

I have an Azure Function triggered by BlobTrigger. I'm using the `TraceWriter log` parameter as [documentation shows](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/functions-reference-csharp/#logging). I've enabled the Application Logs on the [portal](https://portal.azure.com), specified the container and selected the `Verbose` level (following [this instructions](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log/#enablediag)).

Using the Azure Storage Explorer I can see my "applogscontainer" and some .csv files on it, but with weird info, I mean, without my logs as [this question shows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38251471/c-sharp-webapi-azure-application-logging-not-working).

Using Kudu I found my logs at `D:\home\LogFiles\Application\Functions\function\{functionname}`. How to write those log files in Azure Blob/Table Storage?

Comment: Your logs should show up in table storage. If you go to your Functions monitoring tab, there should be a link to the WebJobs Dashboard, where you can see previous executions. We'll be moving that into the Functions UX soon.

Comment: Hey, just going through our backlog of questions - did you figure this out?

Comment: Hi, yep, I found the logs on `AzureFunctionsLogTable` with my "custom" logs on the `LogOutput` "column". Thank you!

Comment: @ChrisAnderson-MSFT: Is Azure Table an effective medium to store streaming logs? I am trying to pull the invocation logs out but querying data  by timestamp doesn't seem to be a good way to go against Table.

Comment: timestamp should be effective, but Table storage does have some performance issues that we've tried to address via partitioning on the month. That still has issues for high load scenarios. That said, we're going to be adding Application Insights soon which is much more effective. We'll start recommending folks with heavy workloads to use App Insights instead.